# can we autoscale azure container instances connected to the application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am planning to deploy ACI with application gateway but I need to implement autoscaling. I did not found any info of doing so in case of ACI. So can we autoscale ACI which are connected to application gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ACI does not have any built-in auto scaling. If you need something like that, you might want to look at [App Services for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/). Depending on what you use it for, that might even remove your need for an AppGateway in front.